# Merge array of dynamically generated objects into single object

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, object

I'm struggling to convert the below JSON into expected JSON format using JavaScript.

Current JSON :

```
    {
  "furniture": {
    "matter": [
      {
        "matter1": "Matter 1 value"
      },
      {
        "matter2": "Matter 2 value"
      },
      {
        "matter3": "Matter 3 value"
      }
    ],
    "suspense": [
      {
        "suspense1": "suspense 1 value"
      },
      {
        "suspense2": "suspense 2 value"
      }
    ],
    "Direct": [
      {
        "System": "System value"
      }
    ],
    "Road": [
      {
        "Road key 1 ": "Road value "
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

expected JSON:

```
{
  "furniture": {
    "matter": {
      "matter1": "Matter 1 value",
      "matter2": "Matter 2 value",
      "matter3": "Matter 3 value"
    },
    "suspense": {
      "suspense1": "suspense 1 value",
      "suspense2": "suspense 2 value"
    },
    "Direct": {
      "System": "System value"
    },
    "Road": {
      "Road key 1 ": "Road value "
    }
  }
}
```

Note: furniture in above code is only static. Apart from that all keys and values are dynamically generated.

Comment: You've got this tagged "typescript"; does that mean you care about strongly typing your array-merging function's output?  Or do you just care about the runtime behavior?  Either way, does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WG5BKN) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks!! Works fine

Comment: So do you care about types or not?  If you're happy with the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71054949/2887218) then I guess you don't, because TypeScript types are absent there and I get compiler warnings about implicit `any`.  Is this really a "typescript" question or do you just care about runtime?

Comment: No it's just runtime behavior. And your answer works absolutely fine for me. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look for arrays and create a joined object, otherwise flat the deeper level.

```js
const
    flat = object => Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(object)
        .map(([k, v]) => [k, Array.isArray(v)
            ? Object.assign({}, ...v)
            : v && typeof v === 'object' ? flat(v) : v
        ])),
    data = { furniture: { matter: [{ matter1: "Matter 1 value" }, { matter2: "Matter 2 value" }, { matter3: "Matter 3 value" }], suspense: [{ suspense1: "suspense 1 value" }, { suspense2: "suspense 2 value" }], Direct: [{ System: "System value" }], Road: [{ "Road key 1 ": "Road value " }] }, Diversity: { "Sistema de direção": "Hidráulica" } },
    result = flat(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Getting ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: do you have object with a single value (no array, no object)?

Comment: Yes,  "Diversity": {
        "Sistema de direção": "Hidráulica"
      },

Comment: then you need a check for object as well. please see edit.

Comment: Thanks!! works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var furniture = {};
for (const property in jsonOrig.furniture) {
  var newObj = {};
  jsonOrig.furniture[property].forEach((value) => {
    for (const prop in value) {
      newObj[prop] = value[prop];
    }
    furniture[property] = newObj;
  });
}

var newJson = { furniture: furniture };
```